# JPA Critera Query In Spring

Tags: jpa

```
public Product findProductById(String id , String subCategoryId)
{   
     return em.find(Product.class, id);      
}
```

In this method pass two parameter. How to retrieve record form product table id and subCategoryId?

Actually I am retrieve record based on Id but apply subCategoryId (with and Condition) Error occour.

Please send also Link explain How it's Work? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

public List  findProductIdSubCategoryIdCategoryId(String categoryId, String subCategoryId,String id)
    {
         CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
         CriteriaQuery criteria = cb.createQuery(Product.class);
         Root product = criteria.from(Product.class);
       cb.equal(product.get("subCategoryId"),subCategoryId);

```
    Predicate csi =  cb.and(cb.equal(product.get("categoryId"), categoryId), cb.equal(product.get("subCategoryId"), subCategoryId),
            cb.equal(product.get("id"), id));

     criteria.select(product).where(csi);
     return em.createQuery(criteria).getResultList();


}
```

It's working fine and attached also link http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Criteria